# How can I get NUnit Testing Result Reports as I am using visual studio and selenium for testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am running test cases from NUnit and trying to get the report or log file.
 How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can use Nunit GUI [link]http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.2 Or use nunit-console,It will create XML result “TestResult.xml”

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Slavas comment:
I assume you do use the nUnit GUI, to save your test results after you ran them, press the menu button 'Tools' -> 'Save Results as XML...'

In the xml file will be an overview of the tests with the notion to each if it passed or failed.

Also in the GUI, if you want to see code output from 'Console.WriteLine()' you can after the test(s) are run, switch the view mode to 'Text Output' (bottom middle of the window). In this output box you can mark all text and paste it to the editor of your choice to work with it.